# Div zone on top of a youtube video

Tags: css, youtube-api

how can I put a div zone on top of my youtube video, the video is using the youtube api

My code on [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtjmsy/HR8pX/27/)

i tried out z-index without success, how would I achieve this ?

Cheers for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played about with your fiddle and hopefully this is good for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/HR8pX/32/

It's really just adding a container with position:relative and absolutely positioning your overlay DIV.

Comment: Hi, Billy, thanks for your answer, I tried out your code, works great in firefox, but doesn' t work in chrome :(

Comment: @dtjmsy - Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/HR8pX/44/  -- I added wmode=transparent on to the end of the youtube URL in the iFrame

Comment: I think that I will be using the html iframe declaration such as this, and not integrated in the script. Cheers